# matlab always fail to validate using inputParser

Tags: matlab

```
function res = display_grid(root_dir, output_dir,varargin)

ip = inputParser;
ip.addRequired('root_dir', @isstr);
ip.addRequired('output_dir', @isstr);
ip.addOptional('width', 160 , @isscalar);
ip.addOptional('height', 120, @isscalar);
ip.addOptional('ext', 'jpg', @isstr);
ip.addOptional('num_x', 5, @isscalar);
ip.addOptional('num_y', 4, @isscalar);
ip.addOptional('interval', 5 , @isscalar);
ip.addOptional('int_pix_value', 128, @isscalar);
ip.addOptional('seq_id', '0', @isstr);
```

But When I use it in this way:

```
display_grid('./dataset', './inpection', 'seq_id', '10');
```

it always prompt error like:

```
argment 'width' failed validation isscalar.
```

This is wired because I didn't use width when I use this function.

Comment: This code is incomplete and doesn't reproduce the problem. Please post complete (but minimal) code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to use `addParamValue` instead of `addOptional`.

When using `inputParser`, you have required arguments, optional arguments, and parameter-value arguments. Required arguments come first. Optional arguments come next, and you have to supply them in order. Parameter-value arguments come last, in any order.

What's happening here is that because you've specified all your arguments as optional, it's trying to use the value `seq_id` for width, and it fails the validation `isscalar`. Set them all to `addParamValue` instead.

Comment: Note that recent versions of Matlab have deprecated [`addParamValue`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addparamvalue.html) in favor of [`addParameter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addparameter.html).

Comment: @TroyHaskin Just to be clear: Prior to R2013b, the only method was called `addParamValue`. In R2013b, the method `addParameter` was introduced, and `addParamValue` was no longer recommended (it's just a name change though, it does the same thing). In some future release, it's likely that `addParamValue` will be deprecated. But it hasn't been deprecated yet (as of the current release R2015b), and works across all recent releases. But you're right, in that if you have a recent release you should try to use `addParameter` rather than `addParamValue`, unless you need backward compatibility.

Comment: This is inconsistent with existing MathWorks documentation for `addoptional` :  `addOptional(p,argName,default,validationFcn)` So most certainly the `argName` is needed. How else could you use the value in your function?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Fixed.